# Javascript tag ? syntax question

Tags: javascript

I came across the following code snippet and am confused about what the `not:` is doing. Is it a tag? If so, are there any other uses for it?

```
var foo = {
   not: function(bool) { return !bool; }
}
```

Can you provide me with a possible use scenario for this kind of syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a tag.

It is declaring an object with a property called "not" which is a function.

You can find more details at [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [Javascript syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Objects)

Comment: How dumb I am. still struggling to wind my head around for javascript syntax. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It isn't JSON. JSON is a data format based on a subset of JS that this doesn't conform to.

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript the syntax `{ property: value }` creates an object with the property `property`, whose value is `value`. So your code defined an object which has the property `not`, whose value is a function which returns the negation of its argument.